# Does anyone know if I have written this mixed model correctly in lme4?

Tags: r

All effects should be random except Genotype. Index is a plant trait.

Model from literature: Index=OverallMean+Location+Rep(Location)+Genotype+Location*Genotype+error

Model as I have written in lme4:
lmer(Index~(1|Location)+(1|Rep:Location)+Genotype+(1|Location:Genotype)

I am confused about the difference between Rep(Location) and Location*Genotype but that is how it is written in the paper I am following.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what the authors intended:

lmer(Index ~ Genotype + (1 + Genotype | Location) + (1 | Rep:Location))

That is, a "random slope" for Genotype by location.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I put both my original model and the variation you suggested into lme4 and got the same AIC value and residual plots for both. Do you have any insight as to how important the slope distinction is? Or what I am missing in my understanding of comparing the two models. Thanks again.

Comment: Not important. I was hoping to clarify the location*genotype term in the paper, which is written as an interaction between a random term and a fixed term.  I tend to think of that as a random slope (genotype | location) rather than a random intercept on the interaction (1|location:genotype).